# When to use $\limsup$ or $\liminf$?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

This is a soft question in the sense that I don't have a particular problem in mind, but rather, I have a general confusion:

I understand that (one) of the advantages of using $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of a sequence or a function is that they always exist (as opposed to the $\lim$ which may fail to exist). However, many times I find myself asking the question: why take a $\liminf$ and not a $\limsup$?.

What is the difference between them? Or why choose one and not the other for some computation? or for some limiting process etc.

I know this is a very vague question, and therefore, you are welcome to interpret it as you like. I just want to start to clarify this confusion that I have had for a long time.

Comment: It is a standard proof technique to prove existence of a limit by proving that $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ coincide.

Comment: I like to think of $\lim \inf$ as the "best lower bound for the tail" of a sequence, and $\lim \sup$ as the "best upper bound for the tail". This makes choosing which to look at simple -- am I trying to give an upper or a lower bound for the tail behavior of the sequence?

Comment: Sometimes, one gives the right answer and the other doesn't.  For example, the root test depends on the lim sup.

Comment: That is very useful. So intuitively, Liminf is used to get lower bounds while Limsup is used for upper bounds. @Joe

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks a lot, that is also useful. I want to get an intuition of why and how to use them, not only because if I do a computation the other one doesn't work but rather some idea that will enable me to produce my own proofs and arguments using them

Comment: @Sak Yes, that's exactly right. However it is worth noting that for some problems it's not always completely obvious what type of bound you should be looking for.

Comment: @Joe, thanks that is very very useful!

Comment: Consider the sequence $0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5\dots$.  $\liminf$ is zero and $\limsup$ is infinity.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thanks a lot for the example! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It used to describe  sequences of events which say that under certain
conditions the probability that infinitely many events happen is either zero or one. They are used in the 
[Borel-Cantelli lemmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), which is important since they are closely related to almost sure convergence, thus help us understand it better. They also provide a powerful tool when proving almost sure convergence.

Let $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of events from a sample space $\Omega$.

If  $\omega \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m$, then for every $n\ge 1$ there exists an $m\ge n$ such that $\omega \in A_m$. Thus for $\omega \in  A_m$ for infinitely many values of $m$, or in other words, $A_m$ happens infinitely often.

On the other hand, if $\omega \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A_m$, there exists an $n\ge 1$ such that $\omega \in A_m$. That means that starting from $n$, all $A_m$, $m\ge n$, happen, which also mean that only finitely many $A^c_n$ happen. We say that $A_m$ happen eventually.

Thus,
$$ \{\lim \sup A_n\}^c = \{\lim \inf A_n^c\} $$

Comment: Please read the question, which mainly asks about limsups and liminfs of **real valued** sequences, not set valued ones.

Comment: Furthermore, using `{...}` around the sets in the last formula is a terrible choice, confusing as it is with the universal, probabilistic, convention that $\{L\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\,;\,L(\omega)\}$ for every property $L$ on $\Omega$.